# odi purgelog not filtering sessions

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-data-integrator

I am using ODI 10g. In that, the API OdiPurgeLog is not only purging the logs whose name is specified in the Session filter, instead it is deleting all the other sessions also along with it.

All the logs are getting deleted.

Please help to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Purge Properties]

You need not to mentioned session name in purgetype, Just let it be as Session. 
For each session you can purge that session by calling purgeodilog utility in package.

If you have single session running at a time then you can use start time and end time variable and pass them in start date and end date which can also help you to purge the session as per start and end time.

please let me know if this works.

Comment: But in ODI 10g, there is no field called as 'PurgeType'  in OdiPurgeLog

Comment: Could you please add the screenshot of odipurgelog for odi 10g, i haven't used ODI 10g . or i can suggest an alternative to fetch the session number from current session and delete the entry on the basis of session number ffrom SNP_Session.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the alternative using SNP_Session.